# Convert ReadLine() to int

Tags: c#, parsing, io, integer, readline

I have a file which contains on each line a value from {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3}. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to put all this values in an array of type int like this:

```
int[] linesValue = new int[NUMBER_OF_LINES]; 
int i; 

for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++)
    {
        string tmpVal = reader.ReadLine(); 
        linesValue[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tmpVal);
    }
```

"NUMBER_OF_LINES" is a private int and "reader" is a StreamReader.
When I run the code it gives me the error: "Input string was not in the correct format"
I tried reader.ReadLine().ToString() but it still doesn't work. 
I would really appreciate if you guys can help me with this problem.

Comment: Probably you are trying to convert including break line.

Comment: I guess you get the exception when reading last line because it is empty :)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. 
-Gandarez How should I proceed to ignore the break line ?
-Sriram Shouldn't it just return null ?

Comment: @tudor07: As in all cases of debugging, you should proceed rigorously: by *confirming that the line break is the problem in the first place*. You can do this trivially by inspecting `tmpVal` in the debugger and looking at its contents.

Comment: 1. Ctrl+S in the Notepad++ to be sure that your desired and current file contents are in sync(just in case) 2. Are you sure that your file contains exactly NUMBER_OF_LINES integers? What will happen if it is not(as it probably is)?

Comment: What if `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tmpVal)`?

Comment: Use the debugger, or add some logging, to see what line of the file couldn't be parsed.  Then either fix the file, or prevent those lines from trying to be parsed.

Comment: @Corak, yes- it would be empty string, but without break-line character.

Comment: You can use Int32.TryParse also but it will be slower than doing String.IsNullOrEmpty
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the last line or line breaks as an empty string in your `string` and that can't be converted into `int`, hence the exception. Just add a check for [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
{
    string tmpVal = reader.ReadLine(); 
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tmpVal))
    {
           linesValue[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tmpVal);
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you are maintaining your `index` with this check, hence you may end up with empty entries in your array due to index increment.

You can also use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) and parse each line to `int` array like:

```
int[] array = File.ReadLines("filePath")
    .Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((r)))
    .Select(r => int.Parse((r)))
    .ToArray();
```

Look for using [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method. TryParse group of methods doesn't raise an exception if parsing fails. They return a `bool` indicating if parsing was successful or not, and the parsed value is provided in the `out` parameter.